# refreshing my fragement at specific time not working in android

Tags: android, timer

Hi in the below code I am calculating current time .if current time is equal with my time that time I want to auto refresh My Api.
But it is not working if time reaches also

Can any one help me where I did the mistake

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat mdformat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            currenttime = mdformat.format(calendar.getTime());
        }
        if(currenttime.equals("07:00:00")){
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"refreshing",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    listAccount.clear();
                    fetchJSON();
                    accountAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, 1000);

        }
```

Comment: try to use range of time instead, maybe the delta time is not matching the if condition

Comment: range of a time means can you give me some example

Comment: bigger than 06:59:00 and smaller than 07:01:00 something like that

Comment: or use alarm manager where you can set the time.. check this https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html